# How to select radio buttons by cell value in Excel?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, macros, vba

I have a group of radio buttons with labels in adjacent cells.  How can I arrange for the radio button with the label matching a target cell value to activate?

Here's an equivalent example to what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Here, you can see two radio groups: "buyer" and "destination".  The labels are in column A, the radio groups are in column B, and the target values are in column C.  The values in column C are what we control, and we want to activate the correct radio button by looking up the value of the target cell in the list of labels in column A.  That is, if C2 changed to "Internal", then we want the radio button in cell B4 to activate.  The radio buttons in B7 and B8 will be unaffected as they are in a different group.

Comment: So, just to be clear; when the user clicks on the LABEL, you want the RADIO button to activate.

Comment: No, we want the radio button to activate when the value in the target cell changes to match the label.  (not the OP, but sat next to him :-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to actually read the label value. You can assign the labels to option buttons and change the value of the option selected that way.

You could call this on the Worksheet_SelectionChange

```
Sub reflectCell()
 Dim targetedCell As String
 targetedCell = Range("A1").Text

Select Case UCase(targetedCell)
  Case "RED"
    ActiveSheet.OptionButton1.Value = True
  Case "BLUE"
    ActiveSheet.OptionButton2.Value = True
  Case "GREEN"
    ActiveSheet.OptionButton3.Value = True
End Select
```

End Sub

Unless you mean the label IS a cell value adjacent to the OptionButton
Is the target cell a static Range location or the current ActiveCell?

If the target cell is always the same location you might control the input spelling like this.
[image]

**Here is another simpler approach**

A non-macro solution that works if you can use formulas on the sheet is shown in this screen capture

[image: option buttons example]

Name each option button the same as the Label in column A
Have it's linked cell be another cell (which can be hidden examples in E are the formulas showing in F)  in that cell have it compare the input you provide to each cell label. Only one should end up being TRUE, (see example formulas)

Thus the option in B2 is linked to E2, B3 is linked to E3, B7 is linked to E7 etc.
If you are allowed the extra column with formulas( and they can be anywhere) this is much simpler than using vba

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer.  Yes, the labels are cell values.  the target is a static Range location.  We've been supplied with an "industry standard" spreadsheet designed for human input in this format, and there's a limit to how much we're allowed to change.  We're just trying to automate "clicking" on the correct radio button.

Comment: Any chance to see a small picture, even a couple cells? Might there be dozens of cells and only one item will be selected amongst them? You do mean when you say they are a group of radio buttons, only one may select in the group, right?

Comment: I've updated the question with a link to an example if that makes it clearer.  In general there will only be a few radio buttons per group, but there are many groups.

Comment: Is this a form that changes? How do the entries get made in column C? How many groups do you have in total?

Comment: Ah, so linked cells are bidirectional!  Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.