# In Excel, make radio button active/inactive depending on cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I want to make an Excel radio button active/inactive, depending on the value of another cell.

I made the following attempt:

```
Sub test()
If ActiveSheet.Cells(9, 3).Text = 3 Then
    ActiveSheet.OptionButton20_Click.Active = False
Else
    ActiveSheet.OptionButton20_Click.Active = True
End If
End Sub
```

In the VBA macro window, but I got the following error message:

```
"Object doesn't support this property or method"
```

How can I fix it please? (Excel Mac 2011)

---

To clarify, when I say "inactive", I mean greyed out - I don't just mean that it has not been selected.

For example:

Group 1 of Radio Buttons:
Male o   Female o

Group 2 of Radio Buttons:
Glasses o     Earrings o    Beard o

In this case, if "Female" is selected, I want "Beard" to become unselectable.

---

I now have the following text in my "Module 1":

```
Sub hide_group_box()
ActiveSheet.GroupBoxes.Visible = False
End Sub

Sub disable_radio()
If ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 3).Text = 3 Then
    ActiveSheet.OptionButton65.Enabled = False
End If
End Sub
```

The first thing, which hides the Group Boxes works fine. The second thing doesn't seem to work. Do I still have it wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select radio buttons by cell value in Excel?](http://superuser.com/questions/385387/how-to-select-radio-buttons-by-cell-value-in-excel)

Comment: Thanks. It's a different question, but I have added a clarification.

Comment: The property for which you're looking is called `Enabled`

Comment: Thanks. I still get the error message detailed in my post though. It highlights the line 'ActiveSheet.OptionButton20_Click.Enabled = True'

Comment: Remove the `_Click`?

Answer (score 0):

just so happens I was working on this the other day and had the same problem.

I have three options, Likes, Dislikes, None. Only one can be selected because they are radio buttons.

What you want to do is set your variables as such:

```
Sub doSelectedTest()

    Dim shapeLikes As Shape
    Dim shapeDislikes As Shape
    Dim shapeNone As Shape


    Set shapeLikes = Worksheets("picks").Shapes("Option Button 6")
    Set shapeDislikes = Worksheets("picks").Shapes("Option Button 7")
    Set shapeNone = Worksheets("picks").Shapes("Option Button 8")

    If shapeLikes.ControlFormat.Value = xlOn Then
        MsgBox "Likes"
    End If
    If shapeDislikes.ControlFormat.Value = xlOn Then
        MsgBox "Dislikes"
    End If
    If shapeNone.ControlFormat.Value = xlOn Then
        MsgBox "NONE"
    End If
End Sub
```

So in your case:

```
Dim myShape As Shape
Set myShape = Worksheets("picks").Shapes("Option Button 65")

If ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 3).Text = 3 Then
    myShape.ControlFormat.Value = xlOff
End If
```

Or if Button 65 is desired to be disabled in this scenario, then myShape.ControlFormat.Enabled = False or .Visible = False